# Invalid typecast: convert record to tobject on 64-bit platform

Tags: delphi, casting, 64-bit, record, tobject

it works on 32-bit platform.but not 64-bit
here is the exzample

```
  TVerbInfo = packed record
    Verb: Smallint;
    Flags: Word;
  end;

var
  VerbInfo: TVerbInfo;
  strList : TStringList;
  verb : Smallint;
  flags : Word;
begin
  strList := TStringList.create();
  .....
  verbInfo.verb := verb;
  verbInfo.flags := flags;
  strList.addObject('verb1',TObject(VerbInfo));  //invalid typecast happened here
end;
```

can anyone help me? thank you very much

Comment: Even if works on 32 bit platform, this is not the right thing to do. Either wraps this record into an object, or use a diferent data structure

Comment: Generally, you should not use `packed` keyword in records, it will determine to the compiler to not align this record in memory.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: Re `packed`: That's probably exactly the reason why it's used? So that it predictably fits into an `TObject`.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: Regarding your first comment: Why? I'd say it's a common idiom for using properties like `Tag` or `Data`.

Comment: @UliGerhardt Layout of aligned records are predictable too. After all, the compiler manages it. Using packed here results in the same layout, but with the possibility for mis-alignment of the containing structure.

Comment: @UliGerhardt The method is to add Objects, what OP is doing is called Hack. He should use a diferent data structure.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: Maybe a hack, but also a well known idiom, that saves us some heap allocation and pointer indirections.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas When dealing with a value type it's always a pain in desktop Delphi to have to manage New and Dispose if you store a pointer to the value. That's why people resort to such hacks. With them, no extra lifetime management is required. Clearly in modern Delphi, generic containers are the right idiom.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right. But 64 bit exists only in modern versions. That's why I suggested changing to another data structure

Comment: @MatheusFreitas I don't think anyone (other than Uli) is disagreeing with the suggestion to use generics. I'm certainly not. I'm just trying to give justification for why such casts are used pre-generics Delphi, and why they can be the lesser evil.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see your point, I don't have the experience required to state if It is good or evil. I prefer just to advise to Not do it since the method receives an TObject and records are not Objects. Maybe a well known idiom, but, IMO, I prefer not to do this.

Comment: @David, JFTR: I'm **not** disagreeing with using generics. I just tried to answer the OP's question. And because I'm (still) stuck with D2007, generics are a bit off my radar. :-/

Comment: @UliGerhardt Yes, I was being a little provocative there ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function MakeVerbInfoObject(const AVerbInfo: TVerbInfo): TObject;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Move(AVerbInfo, Result, SizeOf(AVerbInfo));
end;

strList.addObject('verb1', MakeVerbInfoObject(VerbInfo));
```

To retrieve the value you can use a corresponding function like

```
function GetVerbInfoFromObject(AObject: TObject): TVerbInfo;
begin
  Move(AObject, Result, SizeOf(Result));
end;

VerbInfo := GetVerbInfoFromObject(strList.Objects[idx]);
```

Comment: +1, Sorry for previous -1. This solution is very clever. Now that I realise the tricky move

Comment: @Gabriel: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Apparently it worked for the OP. I also don't understand the rest of your comment. The trick OP wants to use and my answer helps implementing is to use the 32/64 bits of a pointer variable to hold a small record.

Answer (score 3):

Your cast `TObject(VerbInfo)` will compile provided that `SizeOf(TObject) = SizeOf(TVerbInfo)`. But `TObject` is a pointer and so its size varies with architecture. On the other hand, `SizeOf(TVerbInfo)` does not vary with architecture. Hence the cast can only work on one architecture.

Using casts like this is how you had to do things in pre-generics Delphi. But nowadays, you should be using generic containers.

For instance, if you have a list and the strings are unique then you can use a dictionary:

```
TDictionary<string, TVerbInfo>
```

If it is possible for there to be duplicate strings then you would need a new record declaration:

```
type
  TVerbInfo = record
    Name: string
    Verb: Integer;
    Flags: Word;
  end;
```

And then store a list of these in

```
TList<TVerbInfo>
```

One final point is that you should avoid using packed records. These result in mis-aligned data structures and that in turn leads to poor performance.

Comment: @taoxl But you'd prefer to stick with those casts and do without the compiler's help huh?  ;-)

Comment: But one must be careful when storing records this way. List[0].Value = 10 will NOT work as expected.

Comment: @boileau No it won't. You'd have to use the rather odd looking `List.List[0].Value`, or assign an entire record value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to run this on different platforms and compare results

```
ShowMessage( IntToStr( SizeOf( Integer ) ) );
ShowMessage( IntToStr( SizeOf( Pointer ) ) );
ShowMessage( IntToStr( SizeOf( TVerbInfo ) ) );
ShowMessage( IntToStr( SizeOf( TObject ) ) );
```

I suspect you cannot do a hardcast, because the sizes differ.

You may try to use workarounds like

```
type TBoth = record
  case byte of
    0: ( rec: TVerbInfo);
    1: ( obj: TObject);
  end;
```

You can also try to use `TDictionary<String, TVerbInfo>` type instead of `TStringList`

Comment: `var both: TBoth; ... both.rec := VerbInfo; StringList.AddObject('xxx', both.obj); or StringList.AddObject('xxx', TObject(both));`

Comment: @Merlin The explanation is that this is a variant record, like a C union. The fields all share the same storage location.

Answer (score 0):

MakeVerbInfoObject will not give you a valid pointer to the record. Instead, it copies the value of the Verb and Flags fields into the Result.

```
type
  PVerbInfo= ^TVerbInfo;
  TVerbInfo = packed record
    Verb: Smallint;
    Flags: Word;
  end;


function MakeVerbInfoObject(const AVerbInfo: TVerbInfo): TObject;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Move(AVerbInfo, Result, SizeOf(AVerbInfo));
end;


procedure Test;
var
   VerbInfo: TVerbInfo;
   List: TObjectList;
begin
  VerbInfo.Verb:= 7;
  VerbInfo.Flags:= 8;

  List:= TObjectList.Create(false);
  List.Add(MakeVerbInfoObject(VerbInfo));

  // AV here!!!!!!!!
  var i:= PVerbInfo(List[0])^.Verb;

  FreeAndNil(List);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Test2;
end;
```

If we want a real pointer to the record, this can be used:
(tested on 32/64 bit)

```
Type
 PVerbInfo2= ^TVerbInfo2;
 TVerbInfo2= packed record
   Verb: SmallInt;
   Flags: Word;
 end;


procedure Test;
var
   VerbInfo: TVerbInfo2;
   List: TObjectList;
begin
  VerbInfo.Flags:= 7;
  VerbInfo.Verb:= 8;

  List:= TObjectList.Create(false);

  //List.add(Pointer(VerbInfo));    // "E2089 Invalid typecast" when compiling on 64 bit

  List.Add(TObject(@VerbInfo));

  // This gives correct values:
  var i := PVerbInfo2(List[0])^.Verb; // Inspect "I"

  FreeAndNil(List);
end;
```

In a Delphi that supports generics, we should definitely use that. The code is much better and much safer:

```
procedure TestModern;
var
   VerbInfo: TVerbInfo2;
   List: TList<TVerbInfo2>;
begin
  VerbInfo.Flags:= 7;
  VerbInfo.Verb:= 8;

  List:= TList<TVerbInfo2>.Create;
  List.Add(VerbInfo);
  var i := List[0].Verb;

  FreeAndNil(List);
end;
```

Comment: Of course `MakeVerbInfoObject` doesn't produce a valid `PVerbInfo` pointer - that's the precise idea about this trick. I added a corresponding "unpacking" function to my answer.

Comment: Your `Test` routine with `VerbInfo2` won't probably work in a real application because you store a pointer to a local variable - this only works in your example because you pack and unpack in one routine.

Comment: (obviously this is **exactly** what we want). - fixed that for you ;-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt - "you store a pointer to a local variable" - Yes. Sure. It is only for testing the code. As you said, it works because it is all in one procedure - a procedure easy to test.

Comment: @UliGerhardt - the original question is unclear. it doesn't state if it wants to store the pointer or the actual field values.