# How can I convert record to pointer on 64-bit platform on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pointers, casting, 64-bit, record

I have a function returns `record` result. And I need to pass it to another method as `Pointer`. It works on 32-bit mode but raises `Invalid type cast` error on 64-bit mode. How can I fix it?

I've tried to look for already known solutions but found only `record` to `TObject` conversion method: [Invalid typecast: convert record to tobject on 64-bit platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680183/invalid-typecast-convert-record-to-tobject-on-64-bit-platform)

```
aTList.Add(Pointer(aRecord)); // aRecord is a result of the function
```

Comment: Can you post the code that works, and the code that's causing the compiler error?

Comment: It doesn't work in 32 bit mode, your record is not a pointer. You want the address of the record (@aRecord).

Comment: It works on 32-bit mode! It's a code of the popular Toolbar2000 components.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz There are no addresses here. This is just an abuse of `TList`. The code is doing a reinterpret cast of a 4 byte record to be a pointer so that it can add it to `TList`. The pointer is never de-referenced and will be cast back to the record type at a later date.

Comment: @David - Thanks, I was struggling to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code can only work if `aRecord` is the same size as a pointer. So it would seem that `aRecord` is 32 bits wide, since the code compiles on 32 bit.

The simplest way to make code that works in both the 32 and 64 bit compilers is to cast first to a 32 bit integer, and then on to a pointer. Like this:

```
Pointer(Cardinal(aRecord))
```

In the opposite direction you would need to reverse the process. Cast first to `Cardinal` an then on to the record:

```
TMyRecord(Cardinal(ptr))
```

FWIW, the solutions that you referred to in the question that you link to work perfectly well. At the implementation level, a `TObject` variable is nothing more than a pointer.

Perhaps it is time to start using generic lists, `TList<TMyRecord>` is your friend here.

Comment: It works and thanks for the advice about generic lists!